FFMpeg in C# with streams
I am trying to crop mp3 using FFMpeg. I need to use streams for both input and output data.
At the moment, I'm trying to use the stream at least only for input data.
        var inputFile = @"D:\TestInput.mp3";
        
        var process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = @"path\to\ffmpeg.exe",
                Arguments = "-i - -vn -acodec copy -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:30 -y D:\\TestFFMpeg.mp3",
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false
            },
            EnableRaisingEvents = true
        };
        
        process.Start();
        
        using (var input = File.OpenRead(inputFile))
        {
            input.CopyTo(process.StandardInput.BaseStream);
        }
        
        process.WaitForExit();

This code generates an error "System.IO.IOException: Channel is closed.", but it performs its task, the output file is created correctly.
At the same time, if I remove the "-to" block from the arguments, it will work

Use
using (StreamWriter stdin = process.StandardInput)
{
    File.OpenRead(inputFile).CopyTo(stdin.BaseStream);
}

Instead of
using (var input = File.OpenRead(inputFile))
{
    input.CopyTo(process.StandardInput.BaseStream);
}


Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately it doesn't work. The problem is probably not related to stream recording, but to FFMpeg and its “-to” argument. The problem also occurs when using libraries. For example, the “Pipe is broken” error occurs in FFMpegCore. As a temporary solution, I decided to use FFMpegCore and just wrap the call in try-catch, ignoring the catch block. It's not the best solution, but I don't have any more ideas.
